# How to stop the mediaplayer when I exit the current activity or leave the app?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I followed a YT tutorial on making an audio player, worked fine, but I noticed while in play, if you exit or press the home button the player doesn't stop.

This is the code
I know next to nothing with android studio and I'm doing this to make a birthday present.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fs);

        ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.FS_layout);
        AnimationDrawable animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) constraintLayout.getBackground();
        animationDrawable.setEnterFadeDuration(2000);
        animationDrawable.setExitFadeDuration(4000);
        animationDrawable.start();

        message = findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        playerposition = findViewById(R.id.player_pos);
        playerduration = findViewById(R.id.player_duration);
        seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);
        btplay = findViewById(R.id.bt_play);
        btpause = findViewById(R.id.bt_pause);

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alove);

        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                handler.postDelayed(this,500);
            }
        };

        int duration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        String sDuration = convertFormat(duration); // if you don't convert this, it will crash this activity
        playerduration.setText(sDuration);

        btplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //hide play bt
                btplay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //show pause
                btpause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //set max seekbar
                mediaPlayer.start();
                message.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                //start handler
                handler.postDelayed(runnable,0);
            }
        });

        btpause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //hide pause
                btpause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //show play
                btplay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //pause media player
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                //Stop handler
                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);

            }
        });
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                //check condition
                if(fromUser){
                    //when drag seekbar and set progress
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                }
                playerposition.setText(convertFormat(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                //hide pause
                btpause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btplay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //set MP to initial pos
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);

            }
        });
    }
    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    private String convertFormat(int duration){
        return String.format("%02d:%02d",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration)));
    }
```

Comment: Use `mediaPlayer.stop(); mediaPlayer.release();`  in `onStop()` callback of the activity

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop and release your media player object when the activity is stopping, ie `onStop()` method of lifecycle.

```
mediaPlayer?.release()
mediaPlayer = null
```

See more details in [Releasing the MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer#releaseplayer)